# FindControl ERROR

Tags: asp.net

need to store additional userinfo in CUW  steps

//register.aspx

```
         <p>
         <b>HomeTown:</b><br /> <asp:TextBox ID = "HomeTown" runat ="server"></asp:TextBox>
         </p>
         <p>
         <b>HomepageUrl:</b><br /> <asp:TextBox ID = "HomepageUrl" runat ="server"></asp:TextBox>
         </p>
         <p>
         <b>Signature:</b><br /> <asp:TextBox ID = "Signature" runat ="server"></asp:TextBox>
         </p>
         </asp:WizardStep>
         <asp:CompleteWizardStep runat="server" />
      </WizardSteps>
   </asp:CreateUserWizard>
```

//THIS is part of  code behind
WizardStep UserSettings = NewUserWizard.FindControl("UserSettings") as WizardStep;

```
     // Programmatically reference the TextBox controls
     TextBox HomeTown = UserSettings.FindControl("HomeTown") as TextBox;...ERROR Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

There is a good chance you've already found an answer to this question or have moved on, but I found this question in my own search and thought I'd provide an answer for anyone else who might be searching.

The problem with the sample above (besides the code that is missing at the top that would tell me what the ID of your step) is that you need to look for controls in each of the steps of the wizard individually. So, if you were looking for a hyperlink in the first step of your wizard then this would find it:

```
TextBox HomeTown = (TextBox)UserSettings.WizardSteps[0].FindControl("HomeTown");
```

If you didn't want to presume that the step with the HomeTown text box would always be the first step in the collection, this would work:

```
WizardStep wizStep (WizardStep)wizSample.FindControl("SampleStepName");
TextBox HomeTown = (TextBox)wizStep.FindControl("HomeTown");
```

In my case, the control I was looking for was in a TemplatedWizardStep, so I had to use the following code:

```
TemplatedWizardStep wizStep = (TemplatedWizardStep)wizSample.FindControl("SampleStepName");
Panel pnlSample =(Panel)wizStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("pnlSample");
pnlSample .Visible = true;
```

---

**Note:** I was using the Wizard class, because the CreateUserWizard class is based on the Wizard I presume that the code above would work for both.