# Finding a control in TemplatedWizardStep

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, wizard, aspwizard

I am making a Wizard Control that contains combo boxes for user input.  I am using `TemplatedWizardStep` for the control over appearance and navigation.  I have learned that accessing a control inside such a step requires use of `FindControl(id)`.

My wizard looks basically like this, stripping out lots of formatting:

```
<asp:Wizard id="wizEntry" runat="server" >
   <WizardSteps>
      <asp:TemplatedWizardStep id="stepFoo" Title="Foo" runat="server" >
         <table id="TableFoo" runat="server" >
            <tr id="Row1">
               <td id="Row1Cell1">
                  <asp:DropDownList id="DDListBar" runat="server" ></asp:DropDownList>
</td></tr></table></asp:TemplatedWizardStep></WizardSteps></asp:Wizard>
```

I want to get the selected value of `DDListBar` inside wizard `wiz`.    My research shows that I should call `FindControl` on the wizard to get the step, then on the step to get the control.  My code:

```
DropDownList ddlBar = null;
bar = (DropDownList)wizEntry.FindControl("stepFoo").FindControl("DDListBar");
```

When I ran this, `bar` came back as `null`.  So I split up the calls to `FindControl`.  I determined that the wizard step was being found properly, but not the combo box.  In fact, the only control in the wizard step was the table.

I hope there's a simple solution that I have not learned, as opposed to FindControl for each level in the nested control hierarchy.

(The legacy code uses a long table with one combo box per row.  The C# code file references those combo boxes directly by ID.  But the table is Too Long, and the customer wants a wizard to break up the data entry into small units.)

Edit 1: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4168601/2615836) was helpful in my research so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since **DDListBar** is nested inside **TableFoo** server control, you need to find it recursively.

Here is a helper method. It searches any control recursively.

### Helper Method

```
public static Control FindControlRecursive(Control root, string id)
{
   if (root.ID == id) 
     return root;

   return root.Controls.Cast<Control>()
      .Select(c => FindControlRecursive(c, id))
      .FirstOrDefault(c => c != null);
}
```

### Usage

```
var ddListBar =  (DropDownList)FindControlRecursive(wizEntry, "DDListBar");
```

Comment: My project has a different version of this method, which keeps calling `FindControl(id)` over `root.Controls`.  But it returns `null`. :(  Do my `tr` and `td` elements need `runat=server`, perhaps?

Comment: Grr.  `System.Web.UI.ControlCollection does not contain a definition for "Cast" blah blah`.  Ditto for `Select`.

Comment: ... until I added `using System.Linq` to my helper class.